# Initial rendering with ng-view fails

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS code shown below works perfectly without the *ng-view*(last but one line in the html). This is the initial page.

There is only one *ng-view* in this page. What is the router setup required for the initial rendering of this page with the *ng-view*? Please note that I am not following any further route in this page yet.

```
<body ng-app="librarysystem" >


<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="SearchListCtrl">

    <h3 class="text-muted">{{theDate  | date : "fullDate"}}</h3>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Library System</h3>
  </div>
      <input ng-model="titleFilter"> Title Filter: {{ titleFilter }}
      <table class="table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr><th colspan="3">Book Shelf</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:titleFilter">
            <td><a href="#/data/{{$index + 1}}" class="thumb">{{$index + 1}}</a></td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">
              {{book.genre}}
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">{{book.title}}</td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">{{book.author}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div> <!-- /container -->
  <div id="two">
  <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

</body>

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <-      
$route <- ngViewDirective
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-  
%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3802:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3930:39)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3807:45
at getService (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3930:39)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3957:13)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:3808:37
```

My routers are these.

```
var module = angular.module('librarysystem',['ngRoute','librarysystemcontroller','libraryServices','libraryFilters']);

module.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/search', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/searchlist.html',
            controller: 'SearchListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/',{
            template: '<p>{{text}}</p>',
            controller: 'controllerTwo'
        }).
        when('/data/:bookId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/data.html',
            controller: 'BookAdditionCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/search'
        });
}])
```

Update : I used the same version of angular JS files using bower. Even though I use bower I failed to copy all files of the same version.

Comment: did you install `ng-route` module?

Comment: Is "controllerTwo" spelt correctly? And a script tag including it in the page present?

Comment: Yes. angular-route.js is included. All the controllers are in a JS which is included. SearchListCtrl is included from the same JS file and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ng-route library and add it as a dependency to the angular app.
Routing is seperated into it's own library.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Install through Bower:

```
bower install angular-route@X.Y.Z
```

Reference script:

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Add as dependency

```
angular.module('app', 
[
  'ngRoute'
]);
```

## Edit

The error outputs a url, which provides loads of useful information.
[error url output](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%20$templateRequest%20%3C-%20$route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective)

The error message is:

```
Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <-  $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective
```

It is more than likely that the `controllerTwo` is requesting a dependency that may be spelled wrong or does not exist.

## Edit 2

You must call module on the angular application. You can do so by using the angular getter notation.

```
angular
.module('librarysystem')
.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
   // Route Code
 }
```

Comment: var module = angular.module('librarysystem',['ngRoute','librarysystemcontroller','libraryServices','libraryFilters']);
angular-route.js is included too.

Comment: Can you share controllerTwo's code? 
Maybe it has a dependency that is missing.

Comment: Actually there is nothing in controllerTwo's code except a scope variable initialization. In fact I am not sure why just <div ng-view></div> doesn't work either without the surrounding <div id="two>. I am new and there is a fundamental error here. I think.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan see Edit2 ... I think maybe your route code had a flaw.